# OpenSSL identifying cookie verify callbacks with DTLS sessions/connections in multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, callback, openssl

I'm having a bit of trouble with my cookie generation/verification callbacks in a multithreaded server (connection per thread). The DTLS stuff requires these callbacks as far as I can tell; my worry is the example code uses global vars for the cookies, and if there are a lot of connections incoming then I'd prefer to have a hash of cookies and connections.

I have two questions:

1. Should I do it this way or is there a better, easier more-OpenSSL
   way?
2. What do I use to identify a callback/cookie as belonging to a particular connection?

With regard to (2), the callbacks (see below) happen a different thread than the connections, so I cannot use the thread id as the hash key. The callbacks are given an SSL* param, and I bet there is someway to get a unique session/connection id from this, but I have no idea how to get it. I've looked at the [docs](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html#DEALING_WITH_CONNECTIONS) but don't see anything that takes an SSL* object and gives a unique number, at least from what I can tell of the method names. What is the best to identify a unique cookie with a connection, given the parameters these callbacks are passed?

I'm working with code based off [Robin Seggelmann's examples](http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls-samples.html). My stuff is [here](https://github.com/a34729t/exp/blob/master/tun2udp/dtls/server3_oo.c).

---

2 global vars:

```
unsigned char cookie_secret[COOKIE_SECRET_LENGTH];
int cookie_initialized=0;
```

2 callbacks use these variables:

```
int generate_cookie(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *cookie, unsigned int *cookie_len) {
    ...
    /* Initialize a random secret */
    if (!cookie_initialized) {
        if (!RAND_bytes(cookie_secret, COOKIE_SECRET_LENGTH))
            ...
```

and

```
int verify_cookie(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *cookie, unsigned int cookie_len) {
    ...
    /* If secret isn't initialized yet, the cookie can't be valid */
    if (!cookie_initialized) return 0;
```

The main server loop sets these callbacks and opens up a new thread for each client connection:

```
void start_server(int port, char *local_address) {
    ...
    SSL_CTX_set_cookie_generate_cb(ctx, generate_cookie);
    SSL_CTX_set_cookie_verify_cb(ctx, verify_cookie);
    ...
    while (1) {
        // accept new conns
        ...
        if (pthread_create( &tid, NULL, connection_handle, info) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(-1);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

While @matt_h's solution works, you should be aware of the consequences that may arise.

As stated in [#rfc4347](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347):

---

4.2. The DTLS Handshake Protocol

> 1. A stateless cookie exchange has been added to prevent denial of service attacks.

4.2.1. Denial of Service Countermeasures

> Datagram security protocols are extremely susceptible to a variety of
> denial of service (DoS) attacks.  Two attacks are of particular
> concern:
>
> 1. An attacker can consume excessive resources on the server by transmitting a series of handshake initiation requests, causing the
>    server to allocate state and potentially to perform expensive
>    cryptographic operations.
> 2. An attacker can use the server as an amplifier by sending connection initiation messages with a forged source of the victim. The
>    server then sends its next message (in DTLS, a Certificate message,
>    which can be quite large) to the victim machine, thus flooding it.
>
> [...]
>
> When the client sends its ClientHello message to the server, the
> server MAY respond with a HelloVerifyRequest message.  This message
> contains a stateless cookie generated using the technique of
> [PHOTURIS].  The client MUST retransmit the ClientHello with the
> cookie added.  The server then verifies the cookie and proceeds with
> the handshake only if it is valid.  This mechanism forces the
> attacker/client to be able to receive the cookie, which makes DoS
> attacks with spoofed IP addresses difficult.  This mechanism does not
> provide any defense against DoS attacks mounted from valid IP
> addresses.

The most important part is:

> The DTLS server SHOULD generate cookies in such a way that they can
> be verified without retaining any per-client state on the server.

---

So in practice you should not store any cookies at all. This also defeats the overall security concept of DTLS' DOS-countermeasures. The goal is **not to** allocate additional resources until the peer is authenticated.

An attacker could easily spam your storage (memory, database, ...) by using fake IP addresses.

---

**Conclusion:** Instead of storing cookies or using the same secret over and over again, we simply generate a specific amount of secrets, store them inside a vault, and randomly pick one upon cookie-creation. Later then we match the cookie against our secrets in that vault.

**Please read the comments below from @Nathaniel J. Smith, where he points out that this solution does not reflect the most appropiate way as described in RFC 4347, where only 2 self-invalidating secrets should be used. My solution should therefor only be looked as a tool for implementing the RFC.**

---

Here is my open-source solution (tested and works):

Project: https://github.com/Burnett01/openssl-cookie-secret-vault

Stack version: https://github.com/Burnett01/openssl-cookie-secret-vault/blob/master/stack/

Heap version: https://github.com/Burnett01/openssl-cookie-secret-vault/blob/master/heap/

---

API (stack version):

```c
#define CK_SECRET_MAX 20
#define CK_SECRET_LEN 16

/*
Vault that contains the secrets 
*/
static unsigned char ck_secrets_vault[CK_SECRET_MAX][CK_SECRET_LEN];

/*
Creates and stores an amount of secrets
into the vault
*/
size_t ck_secrets_generate( size_t amount );

/*
Returns the amount of secrets in the vault
*/
size_t ck_secrets_count( void );

/*
Picks a random secret off the vault
*/
unsigned char *ck_secrets_random( void );

/*
Tests whether cookie matches on of the secrets
in the vault
*/
size_t ck_secrets_exist( unsigned char* peer, size_t plen, 
        unsigned char *cookie, size_t clen );
```

Generate 20 secrets:

```c
printf( "Generated %d cookie-secrets.\n", ck_secrets_generate( CK_SECRET_MAX ) );
```

Generate a cookie with a random secret:

```c
HMAC( EVP_sha256(), (const void*)ck_secrets_random(), CK_SECRET_LENGTH,
        (const unsigned char*)buff, bufflen, result, &reslen );
```

Test whether cookie matches one of our secrets:

```c
if( ck_secrets_exist( buff, bufflen, cookie, clen ) == 1 )
   /* Cookie is valid since we found a matching secret */
else
   /* Cookie is not valid */
```

---

API (heap version):

```c
#define CK_SECRET_MAX 20
#define CK_SECRET_LEN 16

/*
Vault that contains the secrets 
*/
struct Vault
{
  unsigned char **secrets;
  size_t count;
};

/*
Creates and stores an amount of secrets
into a vault
*/
Vault *vault_init( size_t amount );

/*
Destroys a vault
*/
void vault_destroy( Vault *v );

/*
Picks a random secret off a vault
*/
unsigned char *vault_random( Vault *v );

/*
Tests whether cookie matches one of the secrets
in a vault
*/
size_t vault_sec_exists( Vault *v, unsigned char* peer, size_t plen, 
        unsigned char *cookie, size_t clen );
```

Create a vault and generate 20 secrets:

```c
Vault *v = vault_init( CK_SECRET_MAX );
```

Generate a cookie with a random secret:

```c
HMAC( EVP_sha256(), (const void*)vault_random( v ), CK_SECRET_LENGTH,
        (const unsigned char*)buff, bufflen, result, &reslen );
```

Test whether cookie matches one of our secrets:

```c
if( vault_sec_exists( v, buff, bufflen, cookie, clen ) == 1 )
   /* Cookie is valid since we found a matching secret */
else
   /* Cookie is not valid */
```

Destroy the vault:

```c
vault_destroy( v );
```

---

Edit 30/04/2017: I added a stack version example which might be useful:

https://github.com/Burnett01/openssl-cookie-secret-vault/blob/master/stack/example.c

Edit 28/05/2017: I further improved the stack version, and also added a heap version.

Comment: This approach is way better! I fully endorse it over my naive solution

Comment: @matt_h Glad you like it! I also added some documentation and an example.

Comment: Generating a bunch of separate cookies like this is equivalent to having a single fixed cookie you always use; just slower and more complicated. But using a fixed cookie barely provides any security over not using a cookie at all, because the point of the cookies is to make the client prove that they can receive messages from you. If you send the same cookie to everyone, then anyone can use that cookie to spoof messages from any fake source they want. You should at least make it an HMAC of secret+the ip address, and RFC 6347 suggests mixing in a timestamp and the client parameters too.

Comment: Thank's for your response. I did not  cover the "data" (buff) part of the HMAC because this is up to the coder to construct a secure buffer consisting of IP+TS+Params when passing it to ``HMAC()`. The main emphasis of my solution are the secrets that are used to create such cookie to avoid using a single secret repeatedly. The HMAC signature (cookie) is created with your data (buff) + a random secret, and is later matched against all secrets by re-calculating the HMAC with your data. I should make it more clear that the data (buff) must contain the attributes you mentioned. @NathanielJ.Smith

Comment: I shoot, I was reading too quickly and missed the HMAC part :-). That makes it much better! But the use of 20 different secrets is still pointless AFAICT? If HMAC is secure then 1 secret is enough. If HMAC is not secure, then having 20 different secrets just makes it less secure (because now the attacker has 20 different secrets to try to break, instead of just 1).

Comment: @Nathaniel J. Smith, thanks for your response. The reason for the fixed amount of random secrets is explained in RFC 4347 (Page 12):  ``One potential attack [..] is for the attacker to collect a number of cookies from different addresses and then reuse them to attack the server. The server can defend against this attack by changing the Secret value frequently, thus invalidating those cookies.``  Using only one secret for all cookies can be less secure than having a pool of X secrets that are used to sign cookies, unless of course, a single secret is frequently changed on every ``ClientHello``.

Comment: But even then you would need to keep reference of your old and new secret or at least allow a client to handshake with the old and/or the new one. The RFC says: ``If the server wishes that legitimate clients be able to handshake through the transition (e.g., they received a cookie with Secret 1 and then sent the second ClientHello after the server has changed to Secret 2), the server can have a limited window during which it accepts both secrets. [IKEv2] suggests adding a version number to cookies to detect this case.  An alternative approach is simply to try verifying with both secrets.``

Comment: The vault only gives you the tools for handling multiple secrets. Having it generate 2 or X secrets is up to you. I fully agree with you that "20" secrets can widen the attack vectors, whereas 2-4 should be sufficient enough. You could also use ``ck_secrets_generate`` (stack) or ``vault_init`` (heap) to frequently create new randomized secrets to harden the cookie replay attacks even further. Thank you very much for your great input here. I already forgot about this project and you have given me new thoughts on this. Much appreciated!

Comment: I still think you've fundamentally misunderstood what the RFC is saying. It's saying you should *invalidate* old cookies regularly, so I can't steal one cookie and then keep using it over and over forever. Having 20 different secrets that are all valid forever does nothing at all to address this.

Comment: The only reason to have multiple secrets is if your invalidation strategy is to regularly regenerate the secret on a timer, in which case it makes sense to have exactly 2 secrets: the old one, and the new one. But then your regeneration code needs to move the new secret to the old secret, and then generate just the new secret. Regenerating all the secrets at once defeats the purpose of having 2 secrets.

Comment: Now I understand where you are coming from and how this applies to the RFC. I fully agree with what you said @NathanielJ.Smith about just having 2 secrets and regenerating them. This would better reflect the RFC rather than my solution here.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added "Please read the comments below from @Nathaniel J. Smith, where he points out that this solution does not reflect the most appropiate way as described in RFC 4347, where only 2 self-invalidating secrets should be used. My solution should therefor only be looked as a tool for implementing the RFC." - Thank you and greetings

Comment: If I understand correctly, you shouldn't send one of the "2 secrets" as the cookie directly. You have to combine the address of the client with a secret and HMAC it. Otherwise, the attacker may just reuse the cookie for all it's "virtual clients"(with forged source addresses), right?

Comment: @ToddWong This is correct as stated in the RFC: ``The DTLS server SHOULD generate cookies in such a way that they can be verified without retaining any per-client state on the server. One technique is to have a randomly generated secret and generate cookies as:  Cookie = HMAC(Secret, Client-IP, Client-Parameters)``.

In my code this is called ``peer`` where you would provide a buffer containing peer information (ip etc) and using one of the secrets to generate the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Just store a simple map of SSL pointers to cookies.

```
struct cookie_entry { SSL *ssl; unsigned char cookie[COOKIE_SECRET_LENGTH]; }
struct cookie_entry cookie_tbl[100];

struct cookie_entry* find_cookie(SSL *ssl)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    if (ssl == cookie_tbl[i].ssl)
       return &cookie_tbl[i];
  return NULL;
}

int generate_cookie(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *cookie, unsigned int *cookie_len) {

    /* Initialize a random secret */
    if (!find_cookie(ssl)) {
        struct cookie_entry ce* = find_cookie(NULL); 
        if (!RAND_bytes(ce->cookie, COOKIE_SECRET_LENGTH))
}

int verify_cookie(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *cookie, unsigned int cookie_len) {
    /* find_cookie and compare.. */
```

Hope that makes sense. Obviously could be modified to dynamically resize, or use a hash table implementation such as hcreate(3).

Comment: That certainly works. With regards to using the SSL object as a hash key, at least using UTHash I cannot use the object directly, and the address appears to change, so I cannot go after that either. If the SSL object had a unqiue ID, that would be ideal.

Comment: I doubt this is secure. You have to store SSL* for each started handshake. Attacker simply spoofs IP addresses and overwhelms your server's RAM with many handshakes without using resources on his side.